# How to listen to server side events in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, server-sent-events

I am setting up server-sent events on my Expo React Native App via [react-native-event-source](https://github.com/jordanbyron/react-native-event-source) library .

With the function below, I should have `data` logged every 10 seconds. But nothing is printed in the console. Am I missing something?

```js
  getTodayMissions() {
    ...
    const options = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } };
    const eventsurl = `${BASE_URL}/server-events/`;
    const eventSource = new RNEventSource(eventsurl, options);
    const url = `missionstodayapp?userId=${user.id}`;


    console.log('start the watch', eventsurl, url);
    this.eventSource.addEventListener(url, (data) => {
      console.log('started the watch', data);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using android studio emulator, you should use `10.0.0.2` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for your base URL.

Comment: I've finally succeeded to make it work. I had to specify the event name inside the addEventListener method like this:     ```this.eventSource.addEventListener('myEventName', (data) => {
      console.log('started the watch', data);
    });```

Comment: what is 'myEventName' supposed to be? i use 'message' in the browser but that doesnt seem to work here. @ceessay

Comment: in the browser try to use the "onmessage" methode instead of the "addEventListener" like so :

const eventSource = new EventSource(yourURL); 
eventSource.onmessage = e => { console.log(e)}

Comment: got output of eventSource but addEventListener not showing any output .